# UserControl ContentProperty, Content objects are null

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I created a custom silverlight UserControl.  I need to be able to set its content through a "Child" property.  So I used the "[ContentProperty("Child")]" class attribute :

```
[ContentProperty("Child")] 
public partial class SizeableCheckBox : UserControl
{
    public SizeableCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object Child
    {
        get { return contentControl1.Content; }
        set { contentControl1.Content = value; }
    }
```

The XAML of the UserControl looks like that :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border x:Name="brdCheck" />
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl1" />
    </StackPanel
    ...
</Grid>
```

Now if I use my UserControl in my application everything works fine (even in VS2010 design mode) :

```
<my:SizeableCheckBox x:Name="chkTestCheck">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image ... />
        <Textblock x:Name="txtCheckBoxTest" Text="My Checkbox test" />
    </StackPanel>
</my:sizeableCheckBox>
```

But in my code I have a reference to the "**txtCheckBoxTest**" but that object is null on runtime.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to go chkTestCheck.txtCheckBoxTest.Text
unless i am misunderstanding the quesiton